# Deploy a mobile application in private/restricted App store

Tags: google-play, app-store

I have developed a product based mobile application which should only be available and downloadable for my consumers who are using my product.

Please help me understand how the private/restricted app store works.

Is there any way to provide a direct download link from my website?

Comment: Check this one -> http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

Comment: That is only for iOS, not the android play store, which according to his tags, doesn't seem like what hes looking for.

Comment: @MihribanMinaz thanks for your reply. I don't want public people  download my application other than my consumers(people who bought my product) . I am unable to find a solution from your link and also it has information regards iPhone alone.

Answer (score 2):

you could maybe give a try to companies providing enterprise private app store.

With such service you can create your own company app store and host your native apps, this would maybe make your app management easier.
You'll also be able to control distribution, updates and user access. For instance, you can create groups of customers with different right access, they will receive a direct invitation to install your app.

To name a few I can think of [Appaloosa Store](http://www.appaloosa-store.com), Apperian, MobileIron...

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a Google Play Private Channel.

Its basically creating a private channel for your domain, for which only people part of your domain could access the app. There's a setting in your google apps control panel, "*Allow users to access Google Play Private Channel*" which you would have to untick. 
Then when deploying the app check "*Make this application available only to users of my Google Apps domain*".

Have a look at this link, it gives you an in depth guide how to go about publishing an app to a private channel.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/deploy-private-android-apps-on-google-play/

**Alternatively**, you could provide a download link to the actual apk file on your website (once your consumer has paid for the product) and just give them instructions on how to install the it. eg. Enable "Unknown Sources" on Android Settings, then install the apk file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can I provide a direct download link for our IOS App like android?

Comment: As far as I know, iOS doesnt allow installing apps that are not verified by apple. The only way to install apps outside the store is to add their UDID to your developer account, which I highly doubt will work once you have a lot of consumers. They do have something similar to googles private channels, called B2B.